# Problems reverse engineering cpp / asm code (just for the sake of learning)

Tags: c++, assembly, g++, nasm, objdump

I am trying some cpp binary disassembling. I wrote this utterly simple code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int i=0; int i2=0; 
    for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {i2++; std::cout << "\n" << i2;} 
    return 0;
}
```

I then compiled it with g++ using something like:

```
g++ .cpp -o .cpp.bin
```

I then ran a:

```
 objdump -d .cpp.bin
```

Here's what I extracted:

```
;1lim.cpp.bin:     file format elf64-x86-64
;Disassembly of section .init:
_init:
endbr64 
sub    $0x8,%rsp
mov    0x2fd9(%rip),%rax        
test   %rax,%rax
je     1016 <_init+0x16>
call   *%rax
add    $0x8,%rsp
ret    

;Disassembly of section .plt:
.plt:
push   0x2f7a(%rip)       
bnd jmp *0x2f7b(%rip)        
nopl   (%rax)
endbr64 
push   $0x0
bnd jmp 1020 <_init+0x20>
nop
endbr64 
push   $0x1
bnd jmp 1020 <_init+0x20>
nop
endbr64 
push   $0x2
bnd jmp 1020 <_init+0x20>
nop
endbr64 
push   $0x3
bnd jmp 1020 <_init+0x20>
nop

;Disassembly of section .plt.got:
__cxa_finalize@plt:
endbr64 
bnd jmp *0x2f55(%rip)        
nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

;Disassembly of section .plt.sec:
__cxa_atexit@plt:
endbr64 
bnd jmp *0x2f25(%rip)        
nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc@plt:
endbr64 
bnd jmp *0x2f1d(%rip)        
nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

_ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev@plt:
endbr64 
bnd jmp *0x2f15(%rip)        
nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

_ZNSolsEi@plt:
endbr64 
bnd jmp *0x2f0d(%rip)        
nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

;Disassembly of section .text:
_start:
endbr64 
xor    %ebp,%ebp
mov    %rdx,%r9
pop    %rsi
mov    %rsp,%rdx
and    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
push   %rax
push   %rsp
xor    %r8d,%r8d
xor    %ecx,%ecx
lea    0xca(%rip),%rdi       
call   *0x2ef3(%rip)        
hlt    
cs nopw 0x0(%rax,%rax,1) 

deregister_tm_clones:
lea    0x2f19(%rip),%rdi        
lea    0x2f12(%rip),%rax        
cmp    %rdi,%rax
je     1118 <deregister_tm_clones+0x28>
mov    0x2ed6(%rip),%rax        
test   %rax,%rax
je     1118 <deregister_tm_clones+0x28>
jmp    *%rax
nopl   0x0(%rax)
ret    
nopl   0x0(%rax)

register_tm_clones:
lea    0x2ee9(%rip),%rdi        
lea    0x2ee2(%rip),%rsi        
sub    %rdi,%rsi
mov    %rsi,%rax
shr    $0x3f,%rsi
sar    $0x3,%rax
add    %rax,%rsi
sar    %rsi
je     1158 <register_tm_clones+0x38>
mov    0x2ea5(%rip),%rax        
test   %rax,%rax
je     1158 <register_tm_clones+0x38>
jmp    *%rax
nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
ret    
nopl   0x0(%rax)

__do_global_dtors_aux:
endbr64 
cmpb   $0x0,0x2fe5(%rip)        
jne    1198 <__do_global_dtors_aux+0x38>
push   %rbp
cmpq   $0x0,0x2e5a(%rip)        
mov    %rsp,%rbp
je     1187 <__do_global_dtors_aux+0x27>
mov    0x2e86(%rip),%rdi        
call   1070 <__cxa_finalize@plt>
call   10f0 <deregister_tm_clones>
movb   $0x1,0x2fbd(%rip)        
pop    %rbp
ret    
nopl   (%rax)
ret    
nopl   0x0(%rax)

frame_dummy:
endbr64 
jmp    1120 <register_tm_clones>

main:
endbr64 
push   %rbp
mov    %rsp,%rbp
sub    $0x10,%rsp
movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
movl   $0x0,-0xc(%rbp)
movl   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
jmp    11fd <main+0x54>
addl   $0x1,-0xc(%rbp)
lea    0xe2d(%rip),%rax        
mov    %rax,%rsi
lea    0x2e5f(%rip),%rax       
mov    %rax,%rdi
call   1090 <_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc@plt>
mov    %rax,%rdx
mov    -0xc(%rbp),%eax
mov    %eax,%esi
mov    %rdx,%rdi
call   10b0 <_ZNSolsEi@plt>
addl   $0x1,-0x8(%rbp)
cmpl   $0xf423f,-0x8(%rbp)
jle    11cc <main+0x23>
mov    $0x0,%eax
leave  
ret    

_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii:
endbr64 
push   %rbp
mov    %rsp,%rbp
sub    $0x10,%rsp
mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
mov    %esi,-0x8(%rbp)
cmpl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
jne    1260 <_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii+0x53>
cmpl   $0xffff,-0x8(%rbp)
jne    1260 <_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii+0x53>
lea    0x2f1c(%rip),%rax        
mov    %rax,%rdi
call   10a0 <_ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev@plt>
lea    0x2dc4(%rip),%rax        
mov    %rax,%rdx
lea    0x2f03(%rip),%rax        
mov    %rax,%rsi
mov    0x2da0(%rip),%rax        
mov    %rax,%rdi
call   1080 <__cxa_atexit@plt>
nop
leave  
ret    

_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
endbr64 
push   %rbp
mov    %rsp,%rbp
mov    $0xffff,%esi
mov    $0x1,%edi
call   120d <_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii>
pop    %rbp
ret    

;Disassembly of section .fini:
_fini:
endbr64 
sub    $0x8,%rsp
add    $0x8,%rsp
ret
```

I am now trying to interpret it using the following:

```
nasm -f elf64 .asm
```

How can I possibly fix the assembly code, in order to try to compile it with NASM (it's already a slickly modified version from what I got from `objdump`)

Comment: Short answer: you can't easily do that. Longer answer: for starters you should switch objdump into intel syntax mode. Then you need to fix the remaining syntax issues by hand. You also need to remove the constant addresses and use the symbols. You do not need the plt stuff as that will be autogenerated. You'd normally just use the `main` function and let the linker do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>the answer that i found to this question was the following: instead of running the predeceasing quoted commands, using the following:</sub>

```
gcc -S .cpp
```

<sub>this will produce the following code:</sub>

```
    .file   "1lim.cpp"
    .text
    .local  _ZStL8__ioinit
    .comm   _ZStL8__ioinit,1,1
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "\n"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1731:
    .cfi_startproc
    endbr64
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -12(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -8(%rbp)
    jmp .L2
.L3:
    addl    $1, -12(%rbp)
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rsi
    leaq    _ZSt4cout(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc@PLT
    movq    %rax, %rdx
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, %esi
    movq    %rdx, %rdi
    call    _ZNSolsEi@PLT
    addl    $1, -8(%rbp)
.L2:
    cmpl    $999999, -8(%rbp)
    jle .L3
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1731:
    .size   main, .-main
    .type   _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii, @function
_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii:
.LFB2229:
    .cfi_startproc
    endbr64
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -8(%rbp)
    cmpl    $1, -4(%rbp)
    jne .L7
    cmpl    $65535, -8(%rbp)
    jne .L7
    leaq    _ZStL8__ioinit(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev@PLT
    leaq    __dso_handle(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdx
    leaq    _ZStL8__ioinit(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rsi
    movq    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    __cxa_atexit@PLT
.L7:
    nop
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE2229:
    .size   _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii, .-_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii
    .type   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, @function
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
.LFB2230:
    .cfi_startproc
    endbr64
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $65535, %esi
    movl    $1, %edi
    call    _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE2230:
    .size   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, .-_GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .section    .init_array,"aw"
    .align 8
    .quad   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .hidden __dso_handle
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
    .section    .note.gnu.property,"a"
    .align 8
    .long   1f - 0f
    .long   4f - 1f
    .long   5
0:
    .string "GNU"
1:
    .align 8
    .long   0xc0000002
    .long   3f - 2f
2:
    .long   0x3
3:
    .align 8
4:
```

<sub>to then compile it it's just about doing the following:</sub>

```
g++ .s -o .s.bin
```

<sub>to then run it it's just a matter of</sub>

```
./.s.bin
```

<sub>now my question is:</sub>
<sub>how can i do the same with executables or binaries?</sub>

<sub>apparently, the answer resides in using a binary called objconv, which stands for converting c++ binaries into assembly code in a correct way. apparently, it can be installed on any operative system using anaconda packge and environment managers</sub>

<sub>***cheers***</sub>